# COUNTIFS function excel with multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in table as follow:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>State</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High</td>
<td>Work - QA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High</td>
<td>In progress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Low</td>
<td>Investigating</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High</td>
<td>Ready for Deployment - QA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Critical</td>
<td>Investigating</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Critical</td>
<td>Work - QA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Critical</td>
<td>Work - Dev</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

wanted to generate report as follow:

```
Summary Report for DEV
------------------------    
Critical    1
High    2
Low         1
```

**The defects in following status represents that they belong to DEV "Work - Dev, Investigating, In progress"**. So when I create summary report I have to take count of all the defects belonging to above state field.

I did try something like this but failed.

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[#All],[Priority]],"High",Table1[[#All],[State]],{"Investigation", "In progress", "Work - Dev"})
```

Comment: So you just want to count the number of times the critical, high and low priorities show up in the list right?

Comment: What did you do to your table?  All of the HTML code is showing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close.  Your formula returns an array `{0,1,1}`, so you need to `SUM` it:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[[#All],[Priority]],"High",Table1[[#All],[State]],{"Investigation","In progress","Work - Dev"}))
```